# Type the character of 0xff value on notepad++

Tags: bash

Please help me do this:

I am writing a bash script file on notepad++ that has content like below:

```
# usb is /dev/tyUSB0
usb=$1
echo "mtest 0x8007FFC0 0x8017ffc0" >> $usb
sleep 115
echo "?1" >> $usb
sleep 1
echo "?2" >> $usb
sleep 1
```

where "?1" is 0xFF value
"?2" is 0x03 value (ctrl + C)

I expect that these 2 characters will be sent to USB device when I run ./script /dev/ttyUSB0 but I can not type 0xFF and 0x03 value on notepad++ (even other editor)

Is there any way to do it?

(Sory becausu English is not my mother tongue)

I could not perform

Comment: See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/). You are attempting to type characters in the "Extended ASCII" character set. These are OS and terminal defined. Unless your application provides a specific way of entering key-combinations that produce that range of character --  you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf`

```
# usb is /dev/tyUSB0
usb=$1
echo "mtest 0x8007FFC0 0x8017ffc0" >> $usb
sleep 115
printf '\177' >> $usb
sleep 1
printf '\003' >> $usb
sleep 1
```